# After connecting SFSC and SFMC we see TWO EMAIL FIELDS in All Subscribers... huh?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, marketing-cloud-connect, subscriber

we recently connected SFSC and SFMC and while building an automation to manage Email Change of Address we noticed there are two mandatory fields for EMAIL in All Subscribers and we're not sure why.

[image]

What did we do here?  Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: did you map any profile attributes when/ after setting up the connector? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_map_attribute_fields.htm&type=5

Comment: Without knowing, it looks like someone one the team created a new field in All Subscribers... I simply deleted it.  Now let's see if that delete messed things up :D